# floor() and ceil() functions vs casting to integer in C

Tags: c, casting, floor, ceil

I am writing some C code to repeatedly round floats up and down to integer values. 
The standard C math library includes the functions `floor()` and `ceil()`. 
I noticed that a much quicker implementation of the functions is to cast directly to integers:

```
int up, down;
float test = 1.3548;

up = (int)(test + 1);  //ceil()
down  = (int)test;     //floor()
```

I did a quick check and this seems to work fine.

1. Is this a reliable method to round up and down if I need the result to be an integer, as an array index (i.e. will it always return the correct results)?
2. Is there a strong reason for the significant increase in speed? (on my system it runs about 3 times faster than the math.h implementation)

Comment: Not a reliable method. Consider the case where `test` is an integer value, such as `4.0`. In this case, `floor(x) == ceil(x)`, but your code would return `up = 5; down = 4`.

Comment: Are you sure it's quicker? Show us your performance test!

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "reliable". If "reliable" means "it will work", then, yes. But if you mean something more, like "it will always round down/up/nearest/to zero/etc...", then, no... Make sure to try your various methods on both positive and negative numbers, as well as those that might be outside the range of `int` to see what happens so you can select the "correct" method for your particular situation... Oh, and that should probably be `up = (int)(test + 0.5)` - think about it...

Comment: If you don't care about older processors, compile with SSE4.1. Then `floor()` and `ceil()` won't be slow anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functions `ceil()` and `floor()` will return different numbers than what you get by using

```
up = (int)(test + 1);
down  = (int)test;
```

when you have a negative number.

If you have:

```
float test = -1.3548;
up = (int)test;        // ceil()
down = (int)(test-1);  // floor()
```

Even the last statement is not a good way to compute `floor()` when `test` is an integral number.

Unless you want to deal with positive and negative numbers differently, and the special cases of when `test` is integral number, you are better off using `ceil()` and `floor()`.

Comment: and for `round()` use: `(int)(test + 0.5f)`

Comment: `(int)(test - 1)` is not equivalent with `floor()` for integral negative numbers.

Comment: @Iggy for "for round() use: (int)(test + 0.5f)" fails for negative numbers.