String casting by dividing by 1?
I am trying to debug a piece of legacy code.  The code works fine for values up to 9 digits, but starts to throw weird errors for values greater than 9 digits.  I know it has something to do with the type casting, but I can't figure out what.
This is the code:
int a = 0;
char numbuff[15] = "999999999"; //nine digits long works

printf("%s\n",numbuff);
printf("%f\n",atof(numbuff));

a = atof(numbuff) / 1;  //I think they are dividing by 1 to cast to int?

printf("%d\n",a);

When I run this using numbuff of nine digits , I get the expected result:
999999999
999999999.000000
999999999

But when I run it using numbuff set to 10 digits, I get this result:
9999999999
9999999999.000000
2147483647

So I suppose I'm not quite understanding why the original code is dividing the float by 1.  I thought it was to cast the float to an int, but it doesn't work for numbers where there are more than 9 digits.
I believe the code is using atof() instead of atoi() in order to get rid of whitespace in the numbuff string, which makes sense (since numbuff is used throughout for many different numerical lengths).
So at a glance this code seems to make sense, but it isn't working.
What is going on, and how can I fix this code to work for longer numbers?

Using ceil(), floor() or round() would be a much more explicit and clear way to get an integer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286129/floor-and-ceil-functions-vs-casting-to-integer-in-c; though as William says, for things that don't fit in an int, you'll want floorl to return a long.

To make it work for larger numbers, you probably need to change int a; to long a;, but you'll still be bounded by the max value of whatever integer type you use.

Dividing by 1 won't cast it into int as the left operand is still float. Looks like just some remnant of experimentation with  different numbers. And it has nothing to do with the fact that the result does not fit in int.

Why do you (or they) use atof which converts to double when you expect to get an integer number. You might want to use type long and function strtol or long long and strtoll and the corresponding printf format specifiers %ld or %lld respectively. There are also strtoul and strtoull for unsigned types.

Please [edit] your question and add details about the number strings you want to process. Signed or unsigned integer numbers? Minimum/maximum values?

When converting the number as double you might observe the limited floating-point precision. For example atof("9999999999999999") is 10000000000000000.000000.

Dividing by 1 doesn't cast to int. When an expression combines int and double, the int is converted to double, and the result is a double. Whoever wrote the code probably had their own misconception about what the division does.
Assigning the result back to the int variable a is what converts it to int. Making this all explicit, the assignment is equivalent to:
a = (int)(atof(number) / (double)1);

Since dividing by 1.0 has no effect, it's also equivalent to:
a = (int)atof(number);

The reason you're getting strange results for 10 digits is that you're exceeding the possible values of int. If int is 32 bits, the maximum value is 2,147,483,647.
Change a to long (and use %ld as the printf format) and you will get the result you expect, up to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (although this exceeds the precision of double, which is about 17 digits, so you'll lose low-order digits in the atof() conversion).

Is it guaranteed that x / 1.0 == x ?

I don't know if the language guarantees it, but I can't imagine an implementation where it's not true.

Note that you also need to change the printf format specifier to %ld to print a long.
